# Creating crawler through cloud formation for multiple s3 targets

Tags: amazon-s3, web-crawler, aws-cloudformation, target

In side targeti have define like below
Targets:
S3Targets:
- Path: !Ref S3TargetPaths

With this approach getting below error
Property validation failure: [ Value of property { /Targets/S3Targets/0/Path} does not match type {String}

S3TargetPaths is define as parameter with type commadelimetedList

I’m going to create crawler through cloud formation template which is crawle multiple s3 path through single crawler. The count of path is not fixed it will be change as per requirement

Comment: Please provide the template's code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.